# Good rational approximations of pi

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers, pi, approximation

Write a program that prints out all the good rational approximations of pi with denominator < 1000000, in increasing denominator order.  `a/b` is a "good rational approximation" of pi if it is closer to pi than any other rational with denominator no bigger than `b`.

The output should have 167 lines total, and start and end like this:

```
3/1
13/4
16/5
19/6
22/7
179/57
...
833719/265381
1146408/364913
3126535/995207
```

Shortest program wins.

Comment: Does it have to be the string `a/b` or is `a b` also allowed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Golfscript, <strike>71 70</strike> 69 chars

```
2\!:^2^..292^15.2/3]{(.)2/.9>+{\+.((}*;.}do;;]-1%{^0@{2$*+\}/"/"\n}/;
```

(Assumes that you don't pass it anything on stdin)

I don't want to hear any more whinging by people who don't have built-in constants for pi. I don't even have floating point numbers!

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations for the background.

```
# No input, so the stack contains ""
2\!:^2^..292^15.2/3]
# ^ is used to store 1 because that saves a char by allowing the elimination of whitespace
# Otherwise straightforward: stack now contains [2 1 2 1 1 1 292 1 15 7 3]
# Pi as a continued fraction is 3+1/(7+1/(15+1/(...)))
# If you reverse the array now on the stack you get the first 10 continuants followed by 2
# (rather than 3)
# That's a little hack to avoid passing the denominator 1000000

{
    # Stack holds: ... [c_n c_{n-1} ... c_0]
    (.)2/.9>+
    # Stack holds ... [c_{n-1} ... c_0] c_n (1+c_n)/2+((1+c_n)/2 > 9 ? 1 : 0)
    # (1+c_n)/2 > 9 is an ad-hoc approximation of the "half rule"
    # which works in this case but not in general
    # Let k = (1+c_n)/2+((1+c_n)/2 > 9 ? 1 : 0)
    # We execute the next block k times
    {
        # ... [c_{n-1} ... c_0] z
        \+.((
        # ... [z c_{n-1} ... c_0] [c_{n-1} ... c_0] z-1
    }*
    # So we now have ... [c_n c_{n-1} ... c_0] [(c_n)-1 c_{n-1} ... c_0] ...
    #                    [(c_n)-k+1 c_{n-1} ... c_0] [c_{n-1} ... c_0] c_n-k
    ;
    # Go round the loop until the array runs out
    .
}do

# Stack now contains all the solutions as CFs in reverse order, plus two surplus:
# [2 1 2 1 1 1 292 1 15 7 3] [1 2 1 1 1 292 1 15 7 3] ... [6 3] [5 3] [4 3] [3] [2] []
# Ditch the two surplus ones, bundle everything up in an array, and reverse it
;;]-1%

# For each CF...
{
    # Stack holds ... [(c_n)-j c_{n-1} ... c_0]
    # We now need to convert the CF into a rational in canonical form
    # We unwind from the inside out starting with (c_n)-j + 1/infinity,
    # representing infinity as 1/0
    ^0@
    # ... 1 0 [c_n-j c_{n-1} ... c_0]
    # Loop over the terms of the CF
    {
        # ... numerator denominator term-of-CF
        2$*+\
        # ... (term-of-CF * numerator + denominator) numerator
    }/

    # Presentation
    "/"\n
    # ... numerator "/" denominator newline
}/

# Pop that final newline to avoid a trailing blank line which isn't in the spec
;
```

Comment: Well, technically GolfScript has both floating point numbers and constant for PI. It's called `"#{Math.PI}"`.

Comment: @GlitchMr, in what way is a string a floating point number?

Comment: I'd really like to see this unrolled with comments.

Comment: Amazing. The very first line `2\!:^2^..292^15.2/3]` already blew my mind.

Comment: @PeterTaylor [Tied](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21501/46). Can we do better?

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica, <s>67</s> 63

This isn't going to be fast, but I believe it is technically correct.

```
Round[π,1/Range@1*^6]//.x_:>First/@Split[x,#2≥#&@@Abs[π-{##}]&]
```

`Round[π, x]` gives the closest fraction to π in steps of `x`. This is "listable" so `Round[π,1/Range@1*^6]` does this for all fractions down to `1/10^6` in order. The resulting list with many "bad" rational approximations is then repeatedly (`//.`) processed by removing any elements which are farther from π than the preceding one.

Comment: Pretty cool, but I can't test it because I don't have Mathematica.

Comment: @Keith, here's the logic.  `Round[Pi, x]` gives the closest fraction to `Pi` in steps of `x`.  This is "listable" so `Round[Pi,1/Range@1*^6]` does this for all fractions down to 1/10^6 in order.  The resulting list with many "bad" rational approximations is then repeatedly (`//.`) processed by removing any elements which are farther from pi than the preceding one.

Comment: Mathematica beating GolfScript. Neat.

Comment: In 61: `Select[Round[f=Pi,1/Range@1*^6],If[#<f,f=#;True]&@Abs[#-Pi]&]` ... but useless given the dominant bias

Comment: Yarr, Matie. Thar be magic in this code.

Answer (score 7):

### Perl, 77 chars

```
$e=$p=atan2 0,-1;($f=abs$p-($==$p*$_+.5)/$_)<$e&&($e=$f,say"$=/$_")for 1..1e6
```

A minor challenge is that Perl doesn't have a built-in *π* constant available, so I first had to calculate it as `atan2(0,-1)`.  I'm sure this will be beaten by languages more suited for the job, but it's not bad for a language mainly designed for text processing.

Comment: You could change `999999` to `1e6` and save 3 chars.

Comment: @M42: Thanks!  Down to 82 chars now.

Comment: Really nice, $= to get integer. Sorry, I can't upvote twice.

Comment: I can't get this to run: `String found where operator expected at prog.pl line 1, near "say"$=/$_""`

Comment: @KeithRandall: You need the `-M5.01` switch (and Perl 5.10.0 or later) for the `say` command.  Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 5):

### JS (95 characters)

```
for(i=k=1,m=Math;i<1e6;i++)if((j=m.abs((x=m.round(m.PI*i))/i-m.PI))<k)k=j,console.log(x+'/'+i)
```

It does print 167 lines.

Answer (score 5):

### Python, <strike>96</strike> <strike>93</strike> 89 characters

```
a=b=d=1.
while b<=1e6:
 e=3.14159265359-a/b;x=abs(e)
 if x<d:print a,b;d=x
 a+=e>0;b+=e<0
```

#### Python, <strike>95</strike> 93 characters, different algorithm

```
p=3.14159265359;d=1
for a in range(3,p*1e6):
 b=round(a/p);e=abs(p-a/b)
 if e<d:print a,b;d=e
```

**note:** It was less characters to write `p=3.14159265359;` than `from math import*`.  Darn those wordy imports!

Comment: Some shortenings: `1.0` -> `1.`, `10**6` -> `1e6`

Comment: I have updated with your improvements.  Thanks much.

Comment: @KeithRandall, but the second of those makes the output violate the spec.

Comment: In second approach there is no need for variable p. That is 4 chars.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I don't understand.  How does it violate the spec?

Comment: @Ante: Added your improvement.  Moved it to be my first answer.  Thanks.

Comment: You can still save one char by using `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Maybe it's a version-of-Python thing, but for me it's printing the denominator with a trailing `.0`. Although actually it's separating the numerator and denominator with a newline rather than `/` anyway, so I don't suppose it makes much difference.

Comment: The output format isn't quite right - you need to lose the `.0`s and put in a `/`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby 1.9, 84 characters

```
m=1;(1..1e6).map{|d|n=(d*q=Math::PI).round;k=(n-q*d).abs/d;k<m&&(m=k;puts [n,d]*?/)}
```

Comment: @Peter Taylor You're right. You have to use Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

### C99, 113 characters

```
main(d,n){double e=9,p=2*asin(1),c,a=1;for(;n=d*p+.5,c=fabsl(p-a*n/d),d<1e6;++d)c<e&&printf("%d/%d\n",n,d,e=c);}
```

Need to compile with `-lm`, and probably full of undefined behaviour, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala - 180 chars

```
import math._
def p(z:Int,n:Int,s:Double):Unit=
if(n==1e6)0 else{val q=1.0*z/n
val x=if(abs(Pi-q)<s){println(z+"/"+n)
abs(Pi-q)}else s
if(Pi-q<0)p(z,n+1,x)else p(z+1,n,x)}
p(3,1,1)
```

// ungolfed: 457

```
val pi=math.Pi
@annotation.tailrec
def toPi (zaehler: Int = 3, nenner: Int = 1, sofar: Double=1): Unit = {
  if (nenner == 1000000) () 
  else {
    val quotient = 1.0*zaehler/nenner
    val diff = (pi - quotient)
    val adiff= math.abs (diff)
    val next = if (adiff < sofar) {
      println (zaehler + "/" + nenner) 
      adiff 
    }
    else sofar
    if (diff < 0) toPi (zaehler, nenner + 1, next) 
    else toPi (zaehler + 1, nenner, next) 
  }  
}
```

The tailrec annotation is just a check, to verify, that it is tail-recursive, which is often a performance improvement.

Comment: I can't get this to work: `pi.scala:1 error: not found: value math`

Comment: Are you using Scala 2.8?

Comment: My scala says "unknown version", weird.  On ideone.com, they use 2.8.0 and I still get errors.

Comment: Try it at http://www.simplyscala.com/ - works for me. For scala-2.8, replacing `math` with `Math` might be sufficient. I mentioned simplyscala on this metathread, if you happen to search for it again: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/401/373

Comment: OK, that works.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <strike>18</strike> 17 chars

I chose to use, as a measure of "best", the number of terms in a continued fraction representation of π.  By this criterion, the best rational approximations of π are its convergents.

There are 10 convergents of  π with a denominator less than one million.  This is fewer than the requested 167 terms, but I am including it here because it may be of interest to others.

```
Convergents[π, 10] 

(* out *)
{3, 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, 104348/33215, 208341/66317,
312689/99532, 833719/265381, 1146408/364913}
```

If you really want to see the denominator for the first convergent, it will cost an additional 11 characters:

```
Convergents[π, 10] /. {3 -> "3/1"}
(* out *)
{"3/1", 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, 104348/33215,
208341/66317, 312689/99532, 833719/265381, 1146408/364913}
```

---

For those who are interested, the following shows the relations among the convergents, partial quotients, and continued fraction expression of convergents of π:

```
Table[ContinuedFraction[π, k], {k, 10}]
w[frac_] := Row[{Fold[(#1^-1 + #2) &, Last[#], Rest[Reverse[#]]] &[Text@Style[#, Blue, Bold, 14] & /@ ToString /@ ContinuedFraction[frac]]}];
w /@ FromContinuedFraction /@ ContinuedFraction /@ Convergents[π, 10]
```

[image: continued fractions]

Please excuse the inconsistent formatting of the continued fractions.

Comment: That's about half-way to a solution, but it's the easiest half. My GolfScript solution hard-codes a suitable representation of the the continued fraction in only 2 characters more.

Comment: But you didn't use continued fractions for your solution to this question, did you?

Comment: Yes. It was the obvious way to do it.

Comment: In addition to being concise, this is much faster than most or all of the other solutions that have been posted.

Answer (score 1):

## C# <strike>140</strike> 129 chars

```
double n=3,d=1,e=d;while(n<4e5){double w=n/d-Math.PI,a=Math.Abs(w);if(a<e){e=a;Console.WriteLine(n+"/"+d);}if(w>0)d++;else n++;}
```

Uncompressed code

```
var numerator = 3d;
var denominator = 1d;
var delta = 4d;
while (numerator < 4e5) 
{
    var newDelta = (numerator / denominator) - Math.PI;
    var absNewDelta = Math.Abs(newDelta);
    if (absNewDelta < delta)
    {
        delta = absNewDelta;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", numerator, denominator));
    }

    if (newDelta > 0)
    {
        denominator++;
    }
    else
    {
        numerator++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var` is not always your friend. By removing it in favour of `double` you gain the ability to merge declarations, lose the requirement to use double literals, and can save 16 chars. OTOH the question asks for a program, so you'll lose a few to adding a class declaration and a `Main` method.

Answer (score 1):

## J, <sup><strike>69</strike></sup> 65

#### New

```
]`,@.(<&j{.)/({~(i.<./)@j=.|@-l)@(%~(i:3x)+<.@*l=.1p1&)"0>:_i.1e3
```

Still a brute force approach but much faster and a tad shorter.

#### Old

A simple "brute force":

```
(#~({:<<./@}:)\@j)({~(i.<./)@j=.|@-l)@(%~(i:6x)+<.@*l=.1p1&)"0>:i.1e3
```

make a list of  `a/b`s and then discard those that are farther from π for some `b'<b`.

*Note: Change `1e3` to `1e6` for the full list. Go do something else and return later.*